# Reversal of string.contains In python, pandas

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have something like this in my code:

`df2 = df[df['A'].str.contains("Hello|World")]`

However, I want all the rows that *don't* contain either of Hello or World.  How do I most efficiently reverse this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use the tilde `~` to flip the bool values:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["Hello", "this", "World", "apple"]})
>>> df.A.str.contains("Hello|World")
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
>>> ~df.A.str.contains("Hello|World")
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
>>> df[~df.A.str.contains("Hello|World")]
       A
1   this
3  apple

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

Whether this is the most efficient way, I don't know; you'd have to time it against your other options.  Sometimes using a regular expression is slower than things like `df[~(df.A.str.contains("Hello") | (df.A.str.contains("World")))]`, but I'm bad at guessing where the crossovers are.

Comment: Much better than a convoluted negative lookaround test. No experience with Pandas myself, however, so I have no idea what would be the faster approach.

Comment: The regex lookaround test took significantly longer (about 30s vs 20s), and the two methods apparently have slightly different results (3663K result vs 3504K - from ~3G original - haven't looked to see specifics).

Comment: @DSM I have seen this `~` symbol many times, specially in JavaScript. Haven't seen in python. What does it mean, exactly?

Answer (score 9):

The `.contains()` method uses regular expressions, so you can use a [negative lookahead test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) to determine that a word is *not* contained:

```
df['A'].str.contains(r'^(?:(?!Hello|World).)*$')
```

This expression matches any string where the words `Hello` and `World` are *not* found anywhere in the string.

Demo:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["Hello", "this", "World", "apple"]})
>>> df['A'].str.contains(r'^(?:(?!Hello|World).)*$')
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
>>> df[df['A'].str.contains(r'^(?:(?!Hello|World).)*$')]
       A
1   this
3  apple
```

Comment: I got `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings.py:176: UserWarning: This pattern has match groups. To actually get the groups, use str.extract.` from this.

Comment: Made the group non-capturing.